# How to preform the JOIN FETCH query to get the correct result?

Tags: angularjs, join, data-binding, fetch

Ok guys, I got something like this:

A student with ID, Name and Last name...

Now I created a new java class called `ACCOUNTS` with Id, Name and Value

There is also this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<BankAccout> accounts;

public Student() {
    accounts= new HashSet<BankAccout>();
}

    public Set<BankAccout> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(Set<BankAccout> accounts) {
    this.accounts= accounts;
}
```

Now, I have my site, on the site there is a table with the data of all students... they are all unique

Then I had to write a new class, and I have to add a listBox to my site, that shows the selected students accounts...

My old query for calling the student looked like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/getAll")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Student> getAll() {
    return em.createQuery("from Student s").getResultList();
}
```

and the controller for that looks like this:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/CreditCardWEB/rest/cc/getAll').success(
        function(data) {
            $scope.result = data;
        });
```

And it all worked...in the table there were no problems....but i had to change the query to be able to bind the data from the accounts to the table....and now the query looks like this...

```
return em.createQuery("from Student s inner join fetch s.accounts").getResultList();
```

and now, the table SHOULD show me the same data as before...that is, the all students that are all unique....but it shows me only those students that have at least one account....and not only that, but the same student is shown not once, but more times (the number he has accounts) in the table...

Any suggestions?

Comment: What output do you want?  If a student have more than one account, and you don't want to see all of them, then which account(s) do you actually want to see?

Comment: I want to see all the students, regardless if they have an acc or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` filters off records from *either* table which do not match.  Hence, your current join is removing students who do not have an account.  The way around this is to use a `LEFT JOIN`, which will retain all students even if they do not have an account:

```
return em.createQuery("from Student s left join fetch s.accounts").getResultList();
```

Comment: thx man, its close to the answer....now it shows all the students, but the ones with more accounts are shown more times...!

Comment: There is no way around showing more accounts unless you provide additional logic for this.

Comment: what to u need?

Comment: I'm confused.  Why do you want to join to accounts if you don't want account information?

Comment: they need to be added in a separate listBox....i have to select one student, and if he has accs, they ll be shown in that listbox

Comment: Then this approach should work for you.  Just use the collection of accounts for each student.

Comment: Like this:  <select ng-model="student.accounts" multiple="multiple"
        ng-options="account.name for account in student.accounts track by account.id"
        
      >
   </select>

Comment: But still, there are duplicates in the table -.-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127784/discussion-between-newbie-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it is very close to that of Tim.

Here it is:

```
    return em.createQuery("Select distinct s from Student s left join fetch s.accounts").getResultList();
```